# Google Pagespeed return code ranges

Tags: nagios, pagespeed, google-apis-explorer

I've had a look on here but can't seem to find questions relating to the Ranges that are used for the "Good" "Bad" "OK" return values from Googles Pagespeed tests.

The reason i ask, i've just wrote a little Nagios plugin to plot the google Pagespeed of URLs for clients and i wanted to incorporate the Warning and Critical levels on PNP4Nagios in the returned perf data.

Its only really to demonstrate to a client or directors that the site, according to Googles Pagespeed is being classed as Bad or that if a change is made and the Pagespeed is effected, they would be able to see on a nice pretty graph.

I understand in the grand scale of things it means there are a ton of other issues that need to be addressed if it is returning bad but its just for the upper gods really.

Thanks in advance

Craig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean the test results of https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?

In my tests the ranges where as following:

- Poor (Red): 0-59
- Needs Work (Yellow): 60-85
- Good (Green): 86-100

Comment: Much appreciated exactly what i was looking for, Thanks!